# Why does lambda work on new columns generated using pandas.Dataframe.assign in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I often use pandas.DataFrame.assign() in order to method chain in Python.

When calculating values using existing columns, I never have to use lambda. But if I want to create a calculated column using a column I created within the same assign statement, I have to use lambda x. So the code below works, but I simply do not understand why lambda works in the code below.

Let's say I have an existing Dataframe with columns A, B, C.
Using an assign statement, I want to change A by multiplying A and B.
I also create a new column D, by multiplying B and C.
Then I want to multipy C and D (this only works using lambda, why does lambda remember that I created column D but the normal df['D'] * df['C'] does not?

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |

```
df = (df
      .assign(A = df['A'] * df['B'],
              D = df['B'] * df['C'],
              D = lambda x: x['D'] * x['C']))
```

Comment: You can't have two `D=` arguments to a function. Is the last one supposed to be `E=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assigning multiple columns within the same assign is possible. Later items in ‘**kwargs’ may refer to newly created or modified columns in ‘df’; items are computed and assigned into ‘df’ in order.

Firstly it has to do with the order of execution.

With `.assign(A = df['A'] * df['B']`, the `df['A']` is evaluated before `df.assign` executes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1], "B": [2], "C": [3]})
assign = df.assign

def debug_assign(**kwargs):
    print("Hello from: assign()")
    print(datetime.now())
    assign(**kwargs)

df.assign = debug_assign
```

```
>>> df.assign(D = new_value())
Hello from: new_value()
2023-02-14 16:08:38.424683
Hello from: assign()
2023-02-14 16:08:38.424722
```

As for a lambda - it is like a "mini-function", when you declare a lambda, it's like defining a function, nothing is actually executed.

```
>>> lambda x: x['D'] * x['C']
<function __main__.<lambda>(x)>
```

Meaning:

```
>>> df.assign(D = lambda x: x['D'] * x['C'])
```

Is similar to doing:

```
>>> def callback(): return x['D'] * x['C']
>>> df.assign(D = callback)
```

Functions can be assigned to variables and passed as arguments.

```
>>> my_other_print = print
>>> my_other_print
<function print>
```

They're not executed/called until `()` is used - (notice there is no `()` in `D = callback`)

```
>>> my_other_print("hello")
hello
```

pandas checks if something is a ["callable"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign) - if it is, it is run against the current "state", that is, any previous assign arguments that have been computed are included.

Answer (score 1):

Because arguments are evaluated before calling the function. You can't refer to `x['D']` in the argument list before the `D` column has been added to the dataframe.

But when you use a lambda, the evaluation of `x['D']` is deferred until `df.assign()` calls it. It does this after it has processed the `D = df['B'] * df['C']` argument, which creates the `D` column, so it can refer to that column.